# Typescript event binding and unbinding

Tags: typescript

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486930/typescript-event-handler-function-for-event-type-field-incorrect-context) a while ago about delegating jquery events to event handler methods in a typescript class. The answer was to use the following pattern

```
public class LoginDialog { 
     ...
     constructor() { 
        //this.open = this.OpenHandler; //Incorrect way
        this.open = (event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) => {  //Correct way
             this.OpenHandler(this, event, ui);
        }; 
        ...
     }

     public OpenHandler(context: LoginDialog, event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) { 
           //Use context as "this"
     } 
     ...
 }
```

However, now I'm at a similar situation where I need to remove the handler at some time in the future but am unable to because of the anonymous function:

```
public class LoginDialog { 
     ...
     constructor() { 
        this.open = (event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) => {  
             this.OpenHandler(this, event, ui);
        }; 
        this.close = (event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) => {
             this.CloseHandler(this, event, ui);
        }
        ...
     }

     public OpenHandler(context: LoginDialog, event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) { 
           $(window).on("scroll", () => { context.ScrollHandler(context); });
           //$(window).on("scroll", context.ScrollHandler(context)); //Never gets called
           //$(window).on("scroll", context.ScrollHandler); //this = window
     } 

     public CloseHandler(context: LoginDialog, event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) { 
           $(window).off("scroll", () => { context.ScrollHandler(context); }); //Does not remove
     } 

     public ScrollHandler(context: Interfaces.IBaseDialog) { 
           context.jQueryDialog.dialog("option", "position", "center");
           ...
     }
     ...
 }
```

In this case without the arrow syntax in the `on` binding, my `ResizeOrScrollHandler` never get's called, but with it I'm unable to remove the event handler in the CloseHandler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize your problem, you're trying to use jQuery to hook (and unhook) an event on a DOM element, but you want the event handler's 'this' context to point to the class containing the event handler.

There are multiple ways to solve this.

First, you can use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
class LoginDialog {

   public OpenHandler(context: LoginDialog, event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) { 
      $(window).on("scroll", $.proxy(context.ScrollHandler, context));
   }    

   public CloseHandler(context: LoginDialog, event: Event, ui: DialogUIParams) {
      $(window).off("scroll", context.ScrollHandler);
   }
}
```

Another option would be to use [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS#readme), which allows you to treat [events like disposable objects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rxjs-jquery):

```
var scrollSubscription = $(window)
     .onAsObservable("scroll")
     .subscribe(() => console.log("this == the containing class!"));
...
// When we're done, just call .dispose.
scrollSubscription.dispose();
```

Have fun.

Comment: I had a feeling it would involve proxy but I didn't know how to unbind, thanks! Quick question, looking at your subscribe() method, what is the difference between  $(window).on("scroll", () => { context.ScrollHandler(context); });  and   $(window).on("scroll", () => context.ScrollHandler(context));

Comment: And I just encountered a problem with this approach because I cannot get to the event object inside the ScrollHandler. How can I get that in there and still be able to unbind?

Comment: By that I mean the scroll event not the original dialog open event

Comment: Nvm I got it all I had to do was create the parameter in the handler and proxy passed the event automatically. Still would like to know the difference between the 2 lines in my first comment though if you have a min

Comment: Vazgen, there should be no difference between them. Prefer the more concise one.